# Is there a possibility to generate a live reporting in tableau from jira source data?

Tags: jira, tableau-api, reporting

I'm looking for a possibility to generate a live reporting in tableau from Jira source data. I can't use the Tableau connector in Jira, cause of company restrictions. Currently i read out data from the Jira API and don't to were to store them correctly and access them nicely in Tableau.

I expect that i have to use a external database and hope some of you guys already have some experience for this usecase. What is the cheapest variant  for e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried something similar to show the jira servicedesk issue data in a tableau dashboard.
Therefore you need a SQL database (I've used PostgreSQL) in between to crawl the data from the Jira instance.Database provider is secondary, SQL would of course be important for Tableau. I use Postgres because I have had a lot of good experiences with PostgreSQL in combination with tableau.
To crawl the data, to manipulate the data and to upload the data to a postgres Database I created a python script, maybe the raw code helps you --> [GitHub](https://github.com/julian93pj/jira_postgres/blob/main/jira_postgres_query.py)

**1. Get the data from Jira in a Postgres Data Database, something like:**

```
jql = “project in <project_name>\ 
       AND createdDate >= \”2021/01/01\”” 
issues = atc_conn.search_issues(jql,startAt=0, maxResults=0) 
#Default of the search is 50 tickets, set it to 0 to receieve all 
results logging.info(‘Found Tickets for JQL: ‘ + str(issues.total))
```

**2. Write the data in to the Database:**

```
for issue in issues:
Ticket_Key = issue.key
Ticket_Creation = issue.fields.created
Ticket_Project = issue.fields.project.key
#SQL to insert new tickets and update the existing ones
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute
("""
              INSERT INTO jira.reporting
               (ticketkey, createdat, project)
              VALUES
               (%s, %s, %s)
              ON CONFLICT(ticketkey) DO UPDATE
               SET
               createdat=excluded.createdat,
               project=excluded.project;
 """,
(Ticket_Key, Ticket_Creation, Ticket_Project)
)
```

**3. Create a tableau workbook and access the Database**
You need a the postgres/Tableau Connector (more infos [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_postgresql.htm))
Then connect to your database.

**4. Automise the crawling of the data in to your Database**
Therefore I used airflow to schedule the code run. I'm sure you can use any other alternative for that.

To get more informations about my solution check out my **medium article:** https://julianpleli.medium.com/build-your-own-real-time-professional-reporting-tool-for-jira-with-tableau-python-postgresql-fd28b907f562

Answer (score 0):

Or you can connect directly to your Jira database (readonly) from Tableau with SQL request.